# Disable backspace button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a wordpress website. The problem is that when a logged in user logs out, the user can still access the logged in version of the website simply by going to "previous page" by clicking on the "backspace" button in the browser. How can I prohibit this?

Comment: You can't. What you need to do is invalidate the session and make sure that inaccessible URLs redirect to the login page.

Comment: Delete session, redirect to new "logged out" page. Clicking back button would return to previous page where you check if session exists. Since you deleted session, throw error